# Booting from a virtual disk on a virtual machine ends up in a blue screen

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-vista, bsod, virtual-drive, p2v

I took a HDD out of a dead PC (,which used to run Windows Vista) and virtualized it into vhdx using disk2VHD. After converting the VHDX to VMDK, I attached the drive to a new virtual machine on VMWare Workstation. But I can't even boot into Safe Mode ending up in the dreaded blue screen, error codes being: `stop: 0x0000007b (0x8059EBB0, 0xC0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)`

I'd like to keep the drive since it contains data that can be only read using a proprietary software that I can no longer download or reinstall. Can you please point out what I should be working on next?

I tried

- changing disk type(from SCSI to IDE to SATA) in virtual machine settings.
- booting from installation media to do auto repair, which complained it cannot be automatically fixed

,all of which failed without error codes. I ran chkdsk /f and it output no errors.

Comment: that stop code means `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` - you possibly haven't set up the virtual machine correctly, or, perhaps [this article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1013975) may provide some help (not really 100% your situation, but there may be some insight)

Comment: there's also [this complicated guide](https://reviewsvi.com/guide-how-to-fix-stop-code-0x0000007b-2021-guide/) but a comment on that guide suggests a simple solution too

Comment: by the way, there are *many many articles* if you simply search for the phrase `vmware windows vista stop: 0x0000007b`

Comment: @Jaromanda X The complicated guide you linked finally worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If the disk had an error or developed an error wile off for a long while and because of one of these two, there is not not much you can do yourself.

If the VM was created from the raw disk, that may be why it converted.

If the data or app is very important, consider taking the drive to a local recovery agency and see if they can recover anything.

Probably do not get your hopes up.

Comment: I would suggest if OP managed to create an image of the disk, then the disk is fine - sure the data itself may be bad, but, at least the way I interpret your answer is that you are suggesting it could be a failing disk

Comment: There may be part of the disk being bad that is preventing booting .  That is what I am thinking in any event.  or data on the disk corrupted because of age. I think the conversion is just from the raw data and if damaged from age or whatever, that would cause it not to boot.